# Install a Nuget Package from Github Packages Within a Github Action

Tags: github, nuget, github-actions, github-package-registry

I am trying to install a Nuget package that is hosted in Github Packages while running a Github Action.

This command works to add the source and the build is working:

```
dotnet nuget add source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/<ORGNAME>/index.json -n github -u <MY_USERNAME> -p ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} --store-password-in-clear-text
```

So - this is working and my build runs fine.

But - **I'd like to remove `-u <MY_USERNAME>` from the action.** I'd like to use a generic value like `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}`. If I leave the org or whatever - I don't want a dependency on a specific account.

Comment: Can you use anither username? For example tze name of the committer?

Comment: That would require a committer to have access to read the packages (which is almost certainly already the case). I think it would be a good workaround to my issue - but it doesn't feel like a good final solution. I will likely implement this if another option is not available.

Comment: You could use a secret for the username.

Comment: @dan1st that was the workaround I've used previously too. It works well. We use a service account username.

Comment: Are you sure you need a username? It should work with just the token.

Comment: @Max - I'll try it out on Monday.

Comment: @Max a username is indeed required. Otherwise you get the following error message: Both UserName and Password must be specified.

Comment: Hi @jjnguy, wondering whether you found a solution to this.

Comment: -u ${{ github.actor }}

Answer (score 0):

Use --username ${{ github.actor }}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).